# Problems with loading template in django

Tags: python, django

Please help me understand what I am doin wrong. I have started the project in django and in file `settings.py` I set a variable :

```
TEMPLATES_DIR = BASE_DIR+'/templates/'
```

In my project I have a model `test` and in them `view.py` file I added the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.conf import settings
from .models import *

def index(request):
        template = loader.get_template(settings.TEMPLATES_DIR+'index.html')
        test_var = "atata"
        context = {
                'test_var': test_var,
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

And after running I got the following :

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /test/
>
> /var/my_site/templates/index.html

But if I chek it I see this file :

> ls /var/my_site/templates/index.html
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 77 Jan  9 14:18 /var/my_site/templates/index.html*

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, dont concatinate `BASE DIR` with your directory, you need to use `os` module of python, like `BASE DIR` path did.
And honestly beter pas tutorial here http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html , it will help you a lot, for understand basics

Comment: Sorry but i cant understant this moment :
from project.views import test_page

i don't have in views test_page variable, meaby you mean  test_view or test_string? or i not understand whats going on :)

Comment: Like I sayed, dont copy all of my variables and function, read next step, you need to create this view. So, you need to check how python import works, and pass tutorial in djangobook, all become more cleare for you after this.

Comment: great! thx. i'm understand my mistake. i just missclick in my view file. Thank you so much!